# How can I combine words with numbers when pattern matching in LUA?

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I'm trying to match any strings that come in that follow the format `Word 100.00% ~(45.56, 34.76)` in LUA. As such, I'm looking to do a regex close (in theory) to this:

```
%D%s[%d%.%d]%%(%d.%d, %d.%d)
```

But I'm having no luck so far. LUA's patterns are weird.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern is close you neglected to allow for multiple instances of a digit you can do this by using a `+` at like `%d+`.

You also did not use `[`,`(` and `.` correctly in the pattern.
`[`s in a pattern will create a set of chars that you are trying to match such as `[abc]` means you are looking to match any `a`s `b`s or `c` at that position.
`(` are used to define a capture so the specific values you want returned rather then the whole string in the event of a match, in order to use it as a char you for the match you need to escape it with a `%`.
`.` will match any character rather then specifically a `.` you will need to add a `%` to escape if you want to match a `.` specifically.

```
        local str = "Word 100.00% ~(45.56, 34.76)"

        local pattern = "%w+%s%d+%.%d+%%%s~%(%d+%.%d+, %d+%.%d+%)"

        print(string.match(str, pattern))
```

Here you will see the input string print if it matches the pattern otherwise you will see nil.

Suggested resource: [Understanding Lua Patterns](https://www.fhug.org.uk/wiki/wiki/doku.php?id=plugins:understanding_lua_patterns)